# Redirect traffic from an interface to a VPN tun interface with iptables

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to achieve something easy but apparently I'm missing something.

In my box I have a VPN client running which created a `tun0` interface. The box has external traffic coming from the `eth0`.

I would like to forward the traffic from `eth0` to `tun0`. I run the following commands:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -s 192.168.100.0/28 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/28 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Note that I select the source IPs range because I want to forward only certain range.

Running `tcpdump` on the `eth0` interface I can see the traffic coming in from a machine in the range `192.168.100.0/28` but I can't see traffic going into `tun0`.

IP forwarding is naturally on.

I'm not sure what I'm really missing here.

IP configuration of `eth0` is `192.168.10.93/24` while `tun0` is `10.8.8.15/24`

```
➜  ~ ip r
default via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0  metric 100
10.8.8.0/24 dev tun0 scope link  src 10.8.8.15
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 scope link  src 172.17.0.1
172.30.32.0/23 dev hassio scope link  src 172.30.32.1
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0 scope link  src 192.168.10.93  metric 100
```

Comment: The traffic that get into the box does not have destination `192.168.100.0/28` but it has source `192.168.100.0/28`. the destination is the Internet.

Comment: IP configuration of `eth0` is `192.168.10.93/24` while `tun0` is `10.8.8.15/24`.

Comment: `➜  ~ ip r
default via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0  metric 100
10.8.8.0/24 dev tun0 scope link  src 10.8.8.15
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 scope link  src 172.17.0.1
172.30.32.0/23 dev hassio scope link  src 172.30.32.1
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0 scope link  src 192.168.10.93  metric 100
`

Comment: sure. added the required changes

Comment: the destination of the traffic is the Internet generic external IPs. basically a machine generates Internet traffic that is forwarded to the `eth0` interface of this box and from `eth0` must be forwarded to `tun0` and then finally to the Internet. the most important thing is that the traffic leaves from `tun0` because it's a VPN.

Comment: You talk about forwarding from `eth0` (internet) to `tun0` I can not figure out what you actually want to go where. Can you maybe give a better example of a packet that does not work.
A packet that should reach the internet should be forwarded to `eth0` since that is your internet.

Comment: Basically being the `tun0` interface of a VPN, the traffic should reach the Internet via `tun0` so it will appear masqued by the VPN connection.

Basically in plain English what I'm trying to do is:

all incoming traffic to the interface `eth0` with a specific source IP must be forwarded to the Internet via the interface `tun0` so it will appear behind a VPN connection.

Comment: Can you reach internet over `tun0` as well?
I think your understanding of what forwarding is is wrong.
Could you please verify that you are sure what the source, and destination is in the scenarios you are thinking about.

If you have traffic with a destination of "internet" coming in over `tun0` and want that forwarded to the internet, then it is `eth0` that should do MASQUERADE, but that does not work with your explanation of source range.

Comment: Ok I will review all my assumptions and I will let you know.

Comment: Also I will review this https://serverfault.com/questions/571801/tunneling-traffic-from-eth0-to-tun0-openvpn-ububtu-12-04 because it is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. thanks anyway

Comment: but just to explain you the thing because I think I got what you did not understand, the machine with interfaces `eth0` and `tun0` will have to work as a forwarder. take traffic coming in to the interface `eth0` and shot it to the Internet via the `tun0` intertface.

Comment: So tun0 is now internet and not eth0
What is the IP of the gateway on tun0?

Answer (score 1):

Since this in the end might be about having traffic from `192.168.100.0/28` go out over `tun0`
This could be resolved by something like:

```sh
ip rule add from 192.168.100.0/28 lookup 10000
ip route add default via ${tun0gwip} table 10000
```

Also keep the iptables MASQUERADE which is needed unless the tun0 gw can route back to your other network.

Comment: Thanks I'll try and see if it works. But my question is packets from eth0 should be forwarded to tun0. Why my forward command does not work?

Comment: `iptables` is not responsible for where traffic is routed, that is the job of the `routing table`

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `ip rule add` command so I need to explore it but this is what I get
`ip rule add from 192.168.100.0/28 lookup 10000 ip: invalid argument '10000' to 'table ID'
`

Comment: I had to install `iproute2` tool. also I have found exactly all the commands needed and `iptables` is necessary at the end of the day otherwise there is no NATing. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490662/how-to-route-traffic-from-br0-to-tun0-when-tun0-is-not-the-default-route-of-the

Comment: I'm going to upvote your answer @NiKiZe but it's not fully correct in my case. In fact w/o `iptables` won't work.

Comment: You already had MASQURADE part correct so did not include that. Will update to mention that as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact combination of commands that solved the issue:

Create a new route table named `vpn` under

```
➜  ~ cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
#
# reserved values
#
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
#
# local
#
#1  inr.ruhep
1 vpn
```

and then run:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -s 192.168.100.0/28 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

ip route add default dev tun0 table vpn
ip route add 192.168.100.0/28 dev eth0 table vpn

ip rule add from 192.168.100.0/28 table vpn
```